# What am I doing wrong? Not sure why this error keeps popping up

Tags: javascript, sublime-text-plugin

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mxmlc'
[cmd: ['mxmlc', '', '-library-path+=/libs', '-output', '/bin/.swf', '-debug=false', '-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true']]
[dir: /Users/user/go/src/github.com/drk1wi/Modlishka/plugin]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

Trying to run an autocert program in Sublime text. It's probably a simple fix, but I can't find it.

Comment: The program `mxmlc` isn't installed in any of the directories in the search path.

Comment: Are you actually trying to run `mxmlc`, or do you want to use node or npm or something else? What language is your program written in?

Comment: It's written in Go. This is the link where I got the original code from: https://github.com/drk1wi/Modlishka/blob/master/plugin/autocert.go. Pretty sure I need to run mxmlc though.

Comment: No you don't. `mxmlc` is for ActionScript, a dialect of JavaScript. It has nothing to do with Go. Do you have the Golang [distribution](https://golang.org/dl/) installed so you can compile `.go` files and projects? Once you've done that, go to https://margo.sh/b/migrate/ for instructions on installing the `GoSublime` plugin, which includes a Go build system. It may need to be configured first.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have [`mxmlc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mxmlc) installed. You can use `npm` to install it:

```
npm install mxmlc -g
```

Comment: I'm using a MacBook Air and it won't allow me to download an old version of Adobe to use mxmlc. If you know a way around that please let me know